# Tomcat Isn't Scanning JARs Within JARs

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, web-applications, tomcat9

I have two WebApps (say, A.war and B.war) that rely on some common piece of code (say C.jar) to exchange information. So what I did in the two webapps' POM file I added the JAR with the scope "provided".

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>some.web.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>C</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And I copied the C.jar into the Tomcat's lib folder, so that it will be shared. So when I try to deploy any of the war file, by copying the war file to the webapps folder and starting Tomcat, I see a bunch of missing JAR errors on startup:

```
25-Oct-2019 15:07:43.752 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Failed to scan [file:/H:/apache-tomcat-9.0.27/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar] from classloader hierarchy
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: H:\apache-tomcat-9.0.27\lib\logback-classic-1.1.3.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
```

But all the JARs that Tomcat is complaining about are in a "lib" folder of C.jar. Is there a way to make Tomcat scan JARs inside the C.jar. I am not sure if what I am doing is right in the first place. I have played around with Tomcat/Maven before, but never in this detail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need the jar to be the same instance, like, for having common variables at runtime?

Comment: @CarlosLópezMarí Hello, yes I do. There are plenty of objects that are created during run time by either WARs which needs to be saved. Previously i had it in each of the WAR's class path and they all instantiated their own objects, so nothing persisted.

Comment: You mean you need some more info?

Comment: I'm adding the dependency into the tomcat/lib folder and deleting the jar in my .m2 and it stills downloading the source into my repository... Deleting "scoped" prevents the dependency to download and it is getting read from the lib folder...

Comment: Maybe a reading permissions issue?

Comment: WAR files do not support jars inside jars.  You need another solution.

Comment: The JARs are inside JAR, not WAR, C.jar to be specific.

Comment: Jar files cannot contain Jar files without some very serious class loader work.  This simply will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the scanManifest setting under JARScanner set to true in the context.xml of Tomcat. I set it to false and the error went away.

```
<JarScanner scanAllDirectories="true" scanAllFiles="true" scanBootstrapClassPath="true" scanClassPath="true" scanManifest="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

for embedded tomcat (in spring or spring boot) add property

```
server:
  tomcat:
    additional-tld-skip-patterns: "*.jar"
```

or exactly define file name `logback-classic-1.1.3.jar`